# Challenge room locked though I have full health

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I thought these opened if you have full health. I actually had full + 2 blue hearts before dropping a bomb on myself before taking the screenshot.

But even here I have full health... right?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a boss challenge room, not a regular challenge room. You can tell there is a difference because on your minimap, there is a bit of blood on the sword and the skull above the door.

In order to enter, you must have one heart or less remaining (not including the blue hearts)

Comment: In addition to the blood on the sword, there's a skull above the door, while a normal challenge room just has the crossed swords.

Comment: Also, note that you will fight two waves of bosses, rather than 3 waves of generic enemies. This includes Larry Jr.'s, Peep, and Chub, primarily. (In places like the Womb or Cathedral, a *regular* challenge room will uses bosses as well)